# Is it true that Samuel L. Jackson provided the voice of Sergeant William Candy in Terminator 3?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines

In an infamous deleted scene from *Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines*, the origin of the T-800's appearance is explained. It is revealed that Chief Master Sergeant William Candy worked alongside Cyberdyne to develop the Terminator, lending his likeness to the machine. Any I see something regarding this scene online, I always see someone leave a comment that Samuel L. Jackson provided the ridiculous accent for Sgt. Candy. I don't know if this has been confirmed anywhere. Is this true, or just another internet rumor?

[Chief Master Sergeant William Candy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kayFrIR-Qfw)

Comment: It appears to be a case of [citogenesis](https://xkcd.com/978/).

Comment: I have twitted at Sam Jackson. Perhaps he'll respond

Comment: It is **not** true. It's not been stated, so far as I know, who the voice actor was, but it wasn't Jackson.